# Android Action buttons remain from previous view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, master-detail

I have created a master detail view in Android using fragments. (For now I'm considering the phone layout and not the tablet layout).

In my master view, I have a list of items and I show a "add" button in the action bar.

In my detail view, I show the details for the selected item, a "delete" button and a "edit" button in the actionbar.

Now the way I have done it, the "add" button is still present in the action bar in my detail view.

Master class:

```
public class AvailableZonesFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_available_zones, menu);
    }
}
```

Master menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Add">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Detail class:

```
public class ZoneDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_zone_details, menu);
    }
}
```

Detail menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Edit">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/remove"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Delete">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Please post some code, otherwise it is very difficult to spot the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to call

```
menu.clear();
```

as first line in **onCreateOptionsMenu** in your details fragment, to remove menu items from previous fragment.

Comment: This. A coworker told me, that optionMenuIcons are "stacked" on the actionBar when inflating a ned menu.xml

Comment: They are, when using fragments (they have the same activity), thats why you have to call **menu.clear()**, to remove the previous items.

Comment: That would be exactly what I was looking for, thanks.